# Create a reusable audio buffer

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

What is the best way to create a reusable audio buffer with javascript `AudioContext` ?
Is the method `audioCtx.createBuffer()` an option to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the right API call.

Comment: thanks, just found your answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024334/